# Openshift: how to add ssh key to pod

Tags: java, openshift, ssh-keys

I need an ssh key in my Openshift pod to access a server from inside my application logic (Java).
My application tries to add a id_ed25519 file to the pod on startup:

```
String executeString = "mkdir ~/.ssh && echo $SSH_CERT > ~/.ssh/id_ed25519";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeString);
...
```

`$SSH_CERT` is a OS secret string value.

This doesn't throw an error but also doesn't seem to work (`ls ~/.ssh/` in the pods terminal doesn't list anything).
Is ~/.ssh the right place for this file? Is there a different, easier way to add files to a pod?

Comment: Try to use     oc get secrets and check if your secret are properly loaded. After that you probably need pass your secret as env if you not using a framework like Spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution! :)

There were two main problems that I had to solve:

1. Permissions were wrong - the app couldn't create folders or edit the file
2. The stdout and errors of a process aren't logged anywhere by default. Thus I didn't have any error logs that would have helped.

**1. How to solve permissions**

I added the directory and file inside my Dockerfile. Then I gave permissions to the newly created file. Security input: If you can, try not to give permissions to all users like I do (we have dynamic user ids...) but give it to least possible users.

```
RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
RUN touch ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
RUN chmod a+rw ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

**2. How to get proper output**

I added a method that looks like this:

```
private void attachCommandOutputStreams(Process process) {
    InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();
    InputStreamReader errorStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(errorStream);
    BufferedReader errorBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(errorStreamReader);

    // Create a separate thread to read from the error stream
    Thread errorThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = errorBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    log.error(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    errorThread.start();

    try {

        // Read from the standard output stream in the current thread
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.info("Standard output: " + line);
        }

        // Wait for the error thread to complete
        errorThread.join();

        // Close the readers
        bufferedReader.close();
        errorBufferedReader.close();
    } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
        log.error("Error: ", e);

    }
}
```

Then it is called like this:

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", executeString});
 this.attachCommandOutputStreams(process);

 int exitCode = process.waitFor();
 assert exitCode == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Deployment to deploy your java app, you can mount volume from secret:

```
$ oc create secret ssh-secret 
    --from-file=id_rsa=<path/to/ssh/private/key> 
    --type=kubernetes.io/ssh-auth
    -n <projectName>

// 'kubernetes.io/ssh-auth': Credentials for SSH authentication

vi java-app-deployment.yaml
---
kind: Deployment # Or DeploymentConfig
...
...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: *****
      image: ******
      volumeMounts: 
        - name: ssh-volume
          mountPath: /root/.ssh/
          readOnly: true 
  volumes:
    - name: ssh-volume
      secret:
        secretName: ssh-secret
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I do not use OS Deployments.